# What's the proper way to manage a copy of code in git with only differences from the original?

Tags: android, git, version-control

I have an Android app that can be downloaded from the Google market and Amazon market, and I want to have differences in my Amazon version from the main Google version.

My current setup is a develop branch that I merge into my release(master) branch. How would I branch/fork/whatever my code to have an amazon release section where there's only going to be a few differences?

Sorry if that didn't make any sense, and thanks for the help, in advance! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just manage your own branch in the same repository? What sort of differences are you talking about?

You could also look at sumdge/clean scripts to change only small aspects of config. See git attributes: http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html

Comment: This is all in the same repository at the moment, and I just want to know the best way to do this.

And the differences would be something like
`upgradebutton.setAction(new Intent('market link'))`
versus
`upgradebutton.setAction(new Intent('amazon link'))`

Comment: Then just make that change in your branch and unless they change that link, merging the other way should not override it..

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have fairly significant differences (beyond the market URL, etc.) between the two, I highly recommend not managing the differences in branches in source control. Separate out your common code into an Android library project, with different Android applications for Google and Amazon. Otherwise you're going to have to keep pushing commits from some sort of common branch into both Google and Amazon branches.

For the link scenario, you can keep the URL in a string resource and just have different values for the same resource in each application.

**Update:**

See [the doc on Android Library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html).

Comment: Working with submodules and subtrees is a pain. I would highly advise against that. Especially when it's only that.

Comment: I'm not talking about submodules and subtrees. I'm talking about an Android library project. There's no need to deal with this kind of thing through source control when Android already has a solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: ah cool. if that's managed some other way. Do you have a link to show how that works?

Comment: Seems like this option loses the tie to what version of library a specific project is linked to. Ie. if you checkout an older version that used an older version of the library, you don't know exactly which it was. Submodules do this.

Comment: Certainly true that unless you version that library project separately, there are some limitations. In this particular case it doesn't sound like it particularly matters to the OP, but if the need arises, you could version it separately whether in just another repository or a submodule. Either way, I find the Android library approach to be beneficial.